# How to get last column name from a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am passing a datatable to function like below:

```
public static DataTable FindingRowOrder(DataTable mynew) 
{
  // Code 
}
```

My question is how to get the last column name for the `mynew` dataTable?

Comment: Is the code within this method *only* intended to return a column name? If so it should be returning String, not DataTable.

Comment: C# code is...  **string colName = tableName.Columns[tableName.Columns.Count - 1].ColumnName.ToString();**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int count= mynew.Columns.Count;
var lastColumn = mynew.Columns[count - 1];
string columnname= lastColumn.ColumnName;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use LINQ

```
 var lastcol = mynew.Columns.Last().Name;
```

Alternatively you can access it using index.

```
var lastcol = mynew.Columns[mynew.Columns.Count - 1].Name;
```

EDIT: added .Name property.

Comment: no not working showing error

Comment: to work linq, you need to add System.Data.Linq  reffrence

Comment: You need to add `.Name()` method to get name of column.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Tnx. I didn't see that part of the question.

Comment: This needs to be :var lastcol = mynew.Columns[mynew.Columns.Count - 1].ColumnName;

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstColumn1", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstColumn2", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstColumn3", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstColumn4", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstColumn5", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("FirstColumn6", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        string result = GetLastColumnn(dt);
    }
    private string GetLastColumnn(DataTable dt)
    {
        string str = dt.Columns[dt.Columns.Count-1].ColumnName;
        return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var lastcol = mynew.Columns[mynew.Columns.Count - 1].Name;
```